# minimum value of $|2z-1-i|+|3z-2-2i|+|4z-3-3i|$

Tags: complex-numbers, maxima-minima

Find the minimum value of $$P(z) = |2z-1-i|+|3z-2-2i|+|4z-3-3i|$$ where z is a complex number

My try:
I have done this kind of questions and I know the approach is using coordinates. so it can be written as
$$2|z-\frac{1+i}{2}|+3|z-\frac{2(1+i)}{3}|+4|z-\frac{3(1+i)}{4}|$$

all three points $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}), (\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4})$ lie on line $y=x$ so I am able to conclude that required point (for minimum) will also lie on same line. But I am not able to proceed further, please guide me how to deal with coefficients.

Comment: From your own analysis, which I agree with, the function to be minimized can be represented as a function of $~z = x + iy = x + ix.~$  Keeping in mind that (for example) $$\left| ~(x + ix) - (A + iB) ~\right| = \sqrt{(x - A)^2 + (x - B)^2},$$ you can establish the **overall** distance function to be minimized as a function of the single variable $~x.$  Then, setting the distance function as $~f(x),~$ simply examine $~f'(x)~$ and $~f''(x)~$.

Comment: @user2661923 Ok thanks. It worked

Comment: Re last comment, a moderate alternative is to use intuition to reason that when $~f'(x_0) = 0,~$ in this particular setting, you should intuitively expect $~f(x)~$ to have a local minimum at $~x = x_0,~$ rather than a local maximum.  You can verify that this is the case by manually checking the value of $~f(x)~$ for each critical point, if more than 1, as well as on the endpoints of the range.  This strategy should allow you to avoid computing $~f''(x),~$ which is subject to be ugly.

Comment: Think at it geometrically. You have three points $A,B,C$ on a line, with $B$ between $A,C$. You want to minimize $2PA+3PB+4PC$, and determined that $P$ must lie on the same line, which is correct. Now see that $P$ must lie between $A,C$, and break it down into two subcases, where $P$ lies between $A,B$ or $B,C$ respectively, and express the sums in terms of $PA,AB, BC$ then compare and determine $PA$.

Comment: @dxiv sir can u please explain why it's necessary that P will lie on the same line ??

Comment: @Ash_Blanc If you project $P$ to $P'$ on the line then $P'A \le PA, P'B \le PB, P'C \le PC$ so the sum will be smaller - unless $P$ is already on the line.